# How do I send a mail from , from MailID in outlook (programmatically configured from mailid) using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

I'm able to sending the mail using above Outlook dll but I want to send a mail which I configured in the the logic "FROM' MailID only

I'm trying to sending the mail which I configured mail only "FROM", but while I'm sending the mail I'm getting error

> Outlook does not recognize one or more names

where did I make the mistake and how to send the logically written FROM MailID only?

```
 public int sendMFSwitchMail(MAEEmail mAEEmail , string data)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the Outlook application.
                Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                // Create a new mail item.
                Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                //string pathfilecontent = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\payment_failed_mail.html";
                string pathfilecontent = Server.MapPath(@"\payment_failed_mail.html");
                string contentmailstr = "";

                //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mAEEmail.Body))
                //    contentmailstr = File.ReadAllText(pathfilecontent);
                //else
                //    contentmailstr = mAEEmail.Body;


                contentmailstr = File.ReadAllText(pathfilecontent);

                contentmailstr = contentmailstr.Replace("Full_Name", data);

                //contentmailstr = contentmailstr.Replace("Existing_Baskets_Constituents", oldfund);
                //contentmailstr = contentmailstr.Replace("New_Baskets_Constituents", newfund);

                oMsg.HTMLBody = contentmailstr;// sb.ToString();

                //oMsg.HTMLBody = mAEEmail.Body;

                //Subject line
                oMsg.Subject = mAEEmail.Subject;
                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mAEEmail.BCC))
                //    oMsg.BCC = mAEEmail.BCC;


                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;

                // {"Outlook does not recognize one or more names. "}
oRecips.Add(mAEEmail.From);//from mail:abc@cyient.com[outlook, programmatically configured mailid] 
                oRecips.Add(mAEEmail.Password);

                //Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
 Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(mAEEmail.To); // to mail : a@gmail.com

                oRecip.Resolve();
                // Send.
                //Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
                oMsg.Send();

                // Clean up.
                oRecip = null;
                oRecips = null;
                oMsg = null;
                oApp = null;

                //return 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Error is :" + ex.Message.ToString());
                //throw;

                Response.Write("Error is :" + ex.Message.ToString());

                //loggingService.Log("Error is:" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: Please have a look at MailKit: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#sending-messages

Is there a requirement to use Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the sender as one of the recipients, that does not make much sense. The error you are getting means the name cannot be resolved, which means it is not an SMTP address or a name in your contacts. Are you sure you the value if just an SMTP address?

To specify the sender, you need to either set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to one of the `Account` objects from the `Application.Session.Accounts` collection, or, in case of Exchange, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property to the name (not address) of another Exchange user on whose behalf you are allowed to send.